# Angular JS ng-options to access object inside object not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I am trying to create couple select buttons that will be dynamic, and for the first one it worked fine using ng-options.

```
<select ng-options="muscles.name for muscles in bigdata.muscles track by muscles.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Now as for the second one, it simple didnt work, or didnt print.

```
<select ng-options="exercises.name for exercises in bigdata.exercises" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

and the third one, printed the full array, instead of separating it.

```
   <select ng-options="reps for reps in bigdata.muscles.reps" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

My Json file looks like this:

```
{   
"name": "Gym App",
"muscles":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name": "chest",
            "reps": [4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
            "weight": [2,4,6,8,10,12,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30],
            "image": "img/muscles/chest.jpg",
            "exercises": [
                {
                    "name": "ALTERNATING FLOOR PRESS",
                    "rating": 6.1
                }, (and goes on with exercises)...
```

Do objects inside objects need to be treated different?

Thanks

Comment: maybe, it is typo. check that is `bigdata.exercises` correct? or is `bigdata.muscles[0].exercises`?

Comment: So, third one is also typo. replace `muscles` is array, not object. replace to ` bigdata.muscles[0].reps` or iterate it

Comment: Yeah, its was missing the [value] of the array. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes. `muscles` is array, not object.

2) replace from `bigdata.exercises` to `bigdata.muscles[0].exercises`

3) replace from `bigdata.muscles.reps` to `bigdata.muscles[0].reps`

Then, it will work

Comment: To bind them together (muscle and exercise) How exactly would I pass the number of the array? 

maybe doing something like this:
`<select ng-options="muscles.name for muscles in bigdata.muscles track by muscles.id" ng-model="musclesName"  ng-change="exercisesName = musclesName.bigdata.muscles[muscles.id]"></select>`

`<select ng-options="exercises.name for exercises in bigdata.musclesName.bigdata.muscles" ng-model="exercisesName"></select>`

Comment: I think you should replace from `bigdata.muscles[0].exercises` to `firstSelected` (which is `ng-model="selected")`. remove your `ng-change`

Comment: if you share your code somewhere(like jsfiddle), i can help you. i confuse here. sorry, now it is 00:43 in my country